# Erro Publicação Locaweb - ASP.NET com MySql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Publiquei um site na Locaweb: .Net + MySql + MVC 4 + EF6

Para mais detalhes do erro: http://locvip.tempsite.ws/

Detalhe: local roda normalmente.

Porém quando publiquei ocorre o seguinte:

```
`Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods`
```

Comment: Publicar na Locaweb é pura sofrência.

Comment: Está dando este erro pq a DLL do conector que você está usando não e suportada pela hospedagem, você terá que usar uma versão do conector 6.2.5.0 senão me engano! Segue link de download da DLL caso queira tester --> https://groups.google.com/group/dotnet-csharp-es/attach/ee4009040763890d/mysql.data.dll?part=0.1&authuser=0

Comment: Eu baixei a Versão 6.3.9. Adicionei ele na minha aplicação e localmente quando rodo a aplicação dá este problema: The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.3.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882