# Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods EXT.NET - Localweb

Tags: .net, framework

Quando subo meu projeto para a locaweb, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro, alguém sabe como posso resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem uma pergunta aqui na comunidade igual: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76246/erro-publica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-locaweb-asp-net-com-mysql

Comment: Parece que esse LocalWeb é loucura, Amazon EC2 já ouviu falar?

Comment: @Marconi dei mole, comprei semana passada a hospedagem anual da locaweb, só problema até agora, e suporte pessímo

Comment: Entendi, se fosse você eu migrava, só vejo problema nesse Servidor da LocalWeb.

Comment: Os problemas só começaram @ThiagoSouza, sinto muito por você